# how to open popup window in Display tag column link

Tags: javascript, displaytag

How to open popupwindow while clicking on Display tag column.

I have popupSmallWindow(this, 'update') javascript to open the popup. i need to call this from display tag.while clicking this below column.

```
paramName  = "propertyTypeId"
Value = propertyType.propertyTypeId
action= editType.action
```

And need to call popupSmallWindow(this, 'update')

```
<displayEL:column property="propertyType.propertyTypeName" 
                        titleKey="common.propertytype" sortable="true" style="width:30%" />
```

Comment: What is a "display tag column"?

Comment: He's talking about "Displaytag", which is a Java/JSP tool for table layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to write Javascript code to find the column(s) after the page loads. Give the column a class value like "popupHere", and then in your "load" handler you can add a click handler to the cell.

Comment: But i tried defining url inside it for <a href="#" onclick="popupSmallWindow(this, 'update')">content</a> and it worked. But sorting is not working properly. its misbehaving..

Comment: Well it's going to sort by the actual contents of the table cell. You can give the tag a "sortProperty" attribute and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In case it helps. the following is what I use :

```
<display:column property="name" titleKey="org.name"  href="javascript:openWin('#')" paramId="id" paramProperty="id"/> 

<script>
        function openWin(idVal) 
        { 
                idVal= idVal.substring(0, idVal.length-1); 
                var url = 'detail.html?id='+ idVal; 
                window.open(url,'samplePopup','width=600,height=300'); 
        } 
</script>
```

Comment: in second line of your javascript code, you must do like it:  var url = 'detail.html'+ idVal;  because ?id= included in idVal